# Updating Angular 4 to 6 CLI has some error

Tags: angular

I have some error when I want update Angular 4 project to 6.
When I run `cmd /C "set "NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1" && npx @angular/cli@6 update @angular/cli@6 @angular/core@6"` command, that return me errors in below:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YXv8.png)